Cloud Data Fusion Studio - format json file
I need to unpacked and packed a list. Example from
{   "addresses": [     {       "city": "aaa",       "id": "aaa",       "status": "ACTIVE",       "type": "HOME"     },     {       "city": "bbb",       "id": "bbb",       "status": "ACTIVE",       "type": "OFFICE"     }   ] }
to
{   "addresses": [     {       "city": "aaa",       "type": "HOME"     },     {       "city": "bbb",       "type": "OFFICE"     }   ] }
I am using wrangler and I can unpacked using the parse-as-json step. That gives me 2 rows



city
id
status
type




aaa
aaa
ACTIVE
HOME


bbb
bbb
ACTIVE
OFFICE



I can then rebuild it together with write-as-json-object that gives me



addresses




{city:"aaa",type"HOME")


{city:"bbb",type"OFFICE")



and then when I write-as-json-map and export in Google Cloud Storage with json format I have a json that looks like
{city:"aaa",type"HOME")
{city:"bbb",type"OFFICE")

So two separate json structures instead of one
